# vim mapping delayed because of plugin

Tags: key-bindings

I want to map `<leader>h` to `:bprev<CR>`, with my leader key as `\<space>`, so I wrote the following in my init.vim (I also have `nnoremap <space> <Nop>` in my init.vim to override the default normal mode behaviour of `<space>`):

```
nnoremap <space> <nop>
let mapleader = "\<space>"
nnoremap <leader>h :bprev<CR>
```

but I have [airblade/vim-gitgutter](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter) installed which adds a delay to my mapping because of plugin mappings `<space>hp`, `<space>hu`, `<space>hs`:

```
:verbose noremap <leader>h
n  <Space>hp     <Plug>GitGutterPreviewHunk
    Last set from ~/.config/nvim/bundle/vim-gitgutter/plugin/gitgutter.vim
n  <Space>hu     <Plug>GitGutterUndoHunk
    Last set from ~/.config/nvim/bundle/vim-gitgutter/plugin/gitgutter.vim
n  <Space>hs     <Plug>GitGutterStageHunk
    Last set from ~/.config/nvim/bundle/vim-gitgutter/plugin/gitgutter.vim
n  <Space>h    * :bprev<CR>
    Last set from ~/.config/nvim/init.vim
n  <Space>     * <Nop>
    Last set from ~/.config/nvim/init.vim
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637412/unmapping-vim-plugin-mappings) indicates that I can remap plugin bindings by writing my custom bindings in a .vim file in `.config/nvim/after/plugin`, so I tried moving the definition of my mapping there instead along with `<Nop>` bindings for `<space>hp`, `<space>hu`, `<space>hs`, but that doesn't work because my `<Nop>` mappings still delay the execution of my `<space>h` mapping:

```
:verbose noremap <leader>h
n  <Space>h    * :bprev<CR>
    Last set from ~/.config/nvim/after/plugin/keys.vim
n  <Space>hp     <Nop>
    Last set from ~/.config/nvim/after/plugin/keys.vim
n  <Space>hu     <Nop>
    Last set from ~/.config/nvim/after/plugin/keys.vim
n  <Space>hs     <Nop>
    Last set from ~/.config/nvim/after/plugin/keys.vim
n  <Space>     * <Nop>
    Last set from ~/.config/nvim/init.vim
```

How can I override these mappings so that they don't interfere? Also, I have yet to find a decent "best practice" to avoid these types of conflicts - does one exist?

EDIT: I have tried putting `exe :mapclear` at the top of my new `.config/nvim/after/plugin/keys.vim`, but that clears all keybindings from all my plugins and my init.vim which is ... less than satisfactory - however, I don't think it's a terrible idea to move all my keybindings here and not rely on plugin defaults.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

vim-gitgutter follows best practices with respect to mappings.  Specifically, before it makes its maps it checks three conditions:

1. The global variable `g:gitgutter_map_keys` is true.

One option is to `let g:gitgutter_map_keys = 0`, but then *no* mappings will be made and you would have to make the ones you use manually.

2. There is not already a `<leader>hs` map

You can make your own `<leader>hs` map, but this won't help you because it would still cause a delay.

3. There is not already a mapping to `<Plug>GitGutterStageHunk`

In my opinion the easiest method is to use your own preferred mapping,

```
nmap <leader>gsh <Plug>GitGutterStageHunk
```

This allows you to still use the functionality.  Or, you can use a junk mapping;

```
nmap <plug>(disable-ggsh) <Plug>GitGutterStageHunk
```

Do this for all the right-hand-side maps you don't want vim-gitgutter to map to.

A different method, used when plugin do not follow mapping best practices, is to manually unmap what you don't like.  It is easiest to do this in `after/plugin/keys.vim`:

```
nunmap <leader>hs
```

or within the `VimEnter` event:

```
autocmd VimEnter * nunmap <leader>hs
```

Comment: 3. worked for me - adding three nmap lines to my init.vim to override the functions `<Plug>GitGutterStageHunk`, `<Plug>GitGutterUndoHunk`, `<Plug>GitGutterPreviewHunk`. Thank you for also including a workaround for plugins that don't follow best practices! So far I do not need the `after/plugin/keys.vim` file!